# Angular2: Autocompiler watcher doesn't work on file changes

Tags: angular

I'm following quickstart guide of Angular2. I've been able to successfully compile my typescript file to js using 'tsc' command.
However, when I start watcher with 'tsc -w' command the watcher doesn't detect any file changes.
In console I constantly see this line:

> 11:56:25 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.

And no any error or warning messages.

I'm using mac os based vagrant (scotchbox): Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-55-generic x86_64)

Nodejs version: v6.2.1

Npm version: 3.9.3

Can anyone help me with that?

Here is the content of my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

UPD: I've installed nodejs on my mac os, instead of on vagrant box and watcher works fine. However watcher on virtual machine faces the same problem.

Comment: You need to navigate to the project-folder and then run the "tsc -w"-command. If that doesn't work, try running "npm start" while in the project-folder.

Comment: I did it already, same thing:(